# PlantUml to Sequence Diagram

Tags: python, uml, plantuml

I googled it all but not able to find the tool to convert PLANTUML to the sequence diagram in python

Is there any library / tool for converting the plantuml to sequence diagram 
using python?

I understand this online  tool does this : https://www.planttext.com/
but I want to automate the process so I don't want to use the online tool

Edit :

```
@startuml
participant ClassA as Class_UmlA
participant ClassB as Class_UmlB

note right of Class_UmlA: Function to test
    Class_UmlA -> Class_UmlB  : Function1 
    activate Class_UmlA
@enduml
```

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: I don't know how to do this in a python native way (but with a system or pipe command it should be possible) . See for the plantuml package: http://plantuml.com/download

Comment: @albert, Could you point me to the example please

Comment: What kind of example?

Comment: @albert Check the edit section, If I have a plantuml script like this, How do I convert this to sequence diagram?

Comment: The give code is the input for plantuml. This you have to place in a file, say aa.pu, and feed this to file to plantuml and retrieve the generated image, say you want a png file you can retrieve aa.png.  The used command here would be e.g. `java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar %PLANTUML_JAR% aa.pu` (with %PLANTUML_JAR% set appropriately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PlantUML is a Java program, so you need a Java Runtime installed as pre-requirement, but on the other hand you don't need Python.

1) download plantuml.jar from http://plantuml.com/de/download

2) run from commandline 
    `java -jar path/to/downloaded/plantuml.jar path/to/your/plantUMLfile.txt`

your file is generated as `plantUMLfile.png` in the directory of execution.

Use `java -jar plantuml.jar -help` for a full list of parameters to make full use of the commandline tool.